# How do I split a string into three parts(number, digit, space)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, split

How do I split a string into three parts
First "00"
Second "201"
Third "    "(space)

"00201    " this is the string how can i split in three part?

Comment: On what basis do you want to perform splitting?

Comment: yes i am try like this "00201   ".to_s.split("00"),  ans is ["00", "201   "]

Comment: but i don't know how to split after number space

Comment: So your problem is to remove space on the end of the string? Like `rstrip`?

Comment: yes i want to ans like this ["00","201"," ------ "], plz consider as space(--)

Comment: use substring function and your retrieval logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
m = "00201 ".match /(\d{2})(\d{3})(\s)/
m.captures
# => ["00", "201", " "]
```

If you want to match multiple spaces, change the last `(\s)` to `(\s+)`

Comment: @SantoshKumbhar You're welcome, you might wanna check [Ruby's Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-i-match) for more uses.